# Flask template integration with jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, python, templates, flask

There's some jQuery embedded in my Flask template, including a non-standard plugin. I can't figure out how to reference the local copy of the the plugin in my project folder. Do I need to save it somewhere special, or call a reference in my main project?

If, in my template, I reference the remote version of the plugin that's on github (rude, I know, but I just wanted to test it) then it works just fine, so I know I'm having a local issue.

The template looks like this:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

  <script src="jquery.lazyload.js">
    </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
     $("img.lazy").lazyload();
  });
  </script>
```

I tried saving both the .js and the .min.js versions in both the main folder and the templates folder, and still no dice.

Any ideas on how to get my template to see the local plugin?

Thank you

Monica

---

**EDIT:** I've added the .js file to /static, and changed the syntax in the template to:

```
{% raw %}
<script src="

  {{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.lazyload.min.js') }}
  ">
  </script>
{% endraw %}
```

but I'm still getting empty photos as my result.

Comment: by default it's url : /static/whatverfileyou want and file in static directory in project root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Jinja2's template bundler Environment(). In order to execute url_for(), you have to use Flask's built-in template_render().

Removing {% raw %} and using template_render() in the main file does the trick.